# ¿Cómo agrupar el valor máximo de cada mes en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

cree una vista que me muestra el total de las ventas de cada mes desde el el 2018 hasta la fecha la vista se llama "vista_suma_documentos" y es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito obtener el valor mas alto de cada mes, esto quiere decir que me muestre el valor mas alto de enero, el valor mas alto de febrero etc. mostrándome así 12 registros con su mes y año.

la consulta que tengo el la siguiente:

```
select max(documentos),fecha_documentos 
from vista_suma_documentos 
group by month(fecha_documentos)
```

el resultado entregado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al verificar los valores están correctos pero las fechas que los acompañan no lo son ya que esos valores corresponden a otras fechas.

dejo una imagen de un resultado esperado como ejemplo mostrándome el valor mas alto de todos los enero, febrero, marzo etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la creación de la vista es la siguiente:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER = root@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW vista_suma_documentos AS 
    SELECT 
    SUM(cargos.CAVALO) AS documentos, cargos.CAFECO AS fecha_documentos 
    FROM cargos 
    WHERE cargos.CATIPO <> '3' 
    AND cargos.CAFECO BETWEEN '2018-01-01' 
    AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
    GROUP BY YEAR(cargos.CAFECO) , MONTH(cargos.CAFECO)
```

gracias por la ayuda de ante mano.

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte, ¿podrías poner el código de vista? `SHOW CREATE VIEW vista_suma_documentos;`

Comment: CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `vista_suma_documentos` AS
    SELECT 
        SUM(`cargos`.`CAVALO`) AS `documentos`,
        `cargos`.`CAFECO` AS `fecha_documentos`
    FROM
        `cargos`
    WHERE
        `cargos`.`CATIPO` <> '3'
            AND `cargos`.`CAFECO` BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    GROUP BY YEAR(`cargos`.`CAFECO`) , MONTH(`cargos`.`CAFECO`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lo que quieres hacer parece que es esto:

```
SELECT YEAR(cargos.CAFECO) ejercicio,
    MONTH(cargos.CAFECO) mes,
    SUM(cargos.CAVALO) AS documentos,
    MAX(cargos.CAVALO) AS maximo_cargo
    FROM cargos
    WHERE cargos.CATIPO <> '3' 
    AND cargos.CAFECO BETWEEN '2018-01-01' 
    AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
    GROUP BY 1,2;
```

La vista estaba truncando parte de la información que necesitabas, por eso te pedí el código que la generaba.

**Mes con el valor más alto**

Si lo que quieres es quedarte con el mes con el cargo más alto, puedes lograrlo así:

```
SELECT YEAR(cargos.CAFECO) ejercicio,
    MONTH(cargos.CAFECO) mes,
    SUM(cargos.CAVALO) AS documentos,
    MAX(cargos.CAVALO) AS maximo_cargo
    FROM cargos
    WHERE cargos.CATIPO <> '3' 
    AND cargos.CAFECO BETWEEN '2018-01-01' 
    AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
    GROUP BY 1,2
    ORDER BY maximo_cargo DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

En cambio, si necesitas el mes con mayor volúmen, ordena por `documentos`.

**Monto más alto de cada mes**

Si buscas el mejor resultado de cada mes, tendrías que hacer así:

```
SELECT mes,MAX(documentos) mejor_volumen_de_ese_mes,
    MAX(maximo_cargo) mejor_cargo_de_ese_mes
    FROM (
        SELECT YEAR(cargos.CAFECO) ejercicio,
            MONTH(cargos.CAFECO) mes,
            SUM(cargos.CAVALO) AS documentos,
            MAX(cargos.CAVALO) AS maximo_cargo
            FROM cargos
            WHERE cargos.CATIPO <> '3' 
            AND cargos.CAFECO BETWEEN '2018-01-01' 
            AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
            GROUP BY 1,2
    ) c1 GROUP BY 1;
```

**Ejercicio al que corresponde cada máximo**

```
SELECT mes,ejercicio,documentos FROM (
    FROM (
        SELECT YEAR(cargos.CAFECO) ejercicio,
            MONTH(cargos.CAFECO) mes,
            SUM(cargos.CAVALO) AS documentos,
            MAX(cargos.CAVALO) AS maximo_cargo
            FROM cargos
            WHERE cargos.CATIPO <> '3' 
            AND cargos.CAFECO BETWEEN '2018-01-01' 
            AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
            GROUP BY 1,2
    ) c1 JOIN (
        SELECT mes,MAX(documentos) documentos
            FROM (
                SELECT YEAR(cargos.CAFECO) ejercicio,
                    MONTH(cargos.CAFECO) mes,
                    SUM(cargos.CAVALO) AS documentos,
                    MAX(cargos.CAVALO) AS maximo_cargo
                    FROM cargos
                    WHERE cargos.CATIPO <> '3' 
                    AND cargos.CAFECO BETWEEN '2018-01-01' 
                    AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
                    GROUP BY 1,2
            ) c1 GROUP BY 1 
    ) c2 USING(mes,documentos);
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: de esta manera podría ser pero necesito obtener el valor mas alto de cada mes entregándome 12 registros correspondientes a los 12 meses.                            SELECT YEAR(cargos.CAFECO) ejercicio,
    MONTH(cargos.CAFECO) mes,
    SUM(cargos.CAVALO) AS documentos
    FROM cargos
    WHERE cargos.CATIPO <> '3' 
    AND cargos.CAFECO BETWEEN '2018-01-01' 
    AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
    GROUP BY 1,2;

Comment: @FelipeMartinez En los comentarios no va código; es ilegible. Puedes editar la pregunta y añadir info o aclaraciones.

Comment: @FelipeMartinez amplío la respuesta, espero que sea lo que necesitabas

Comment: gracias pero creo que no me he dado a entender bien, pongo en contexto: en la tabla cargos se almacenan todas las ventas, cavalo es donde se almacena el valor de una venta, cafeco es la fecha en el cual se realizo la venta. tengo que sumar todas las ventas y agruparlas por mes, una vez obtenido el total vendido por meses necesito obtener el mejor mes de cada mes, esto quiere decir que si mi filtro es de 2018 a 2022 obtendré 4 meses de enero, febrero etc de estos meses tengo que saber cual tiene el valor mas alto y así por cada mes entregándome 12 resultados con sus respectivas fechas @David JP

Comment: Y eso es lo que hace la última consulta, ¿no? ¿En difiere del valor que esperas?

Comment: @David JP a esa respuesta le falta el año, y si lo coloco se repite y no coincide con el registro original :(

Comment: Entonces, ¿necesitas saber a qué año corresponde ese máximo de entre todos los años? Te modifico la respuesta para que cuentes también con ese dato. Hubiéramos evitado tanta vuelta con un ejemplo sobre unos datos de muestra :)

Comment: @David JP exacto necesito saber eso igual, el ejemplo de la respuesta esperada la deje mas arriba

Comment: Pues ya lo tienes :) Para la próxima déjanos en SQL del dataset de muestra para comprobar el resultado que propones

Comment: gracias eso era lo que necesitaba